# Remesh for 3d printing

Tags: remesh

I need help solving a big problem that takes ages to solve manually. I have a manifold mesh that is 3d printable, but there are a lot of "pockets" left behind the seen surface of the mesh that is connected and cannot be selected in any way automatically. These pockets prints OK, but holds in the resin and cannot be washed properly.

Is there a way of solving this, some kind of remesh that keeps the surface details, while closing small entries to the bigger pockets behind?

[image]

Now I have to manualy edit the mesh in a way to cut the connectors to the outer mesh and than L select the cutoff and delete it or manually sculpt of every pocket out.

Comment: Hello, what do you call "pocket" exactly? Maybe show some screenshots?

Comment: So, I simplified the problem with this image. "pocket" is a sphere. I don't need it as it doesnt show from the outside, but still keeps resin inside after printing, and it's difficult to clean. Is there some automatick way of fixing this? It's hard as blender doesn't see that as a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use a mix of remeshing, displacement, sculpting, and booleans to solve problems like this.

1. Duplicate the Mesh.
   [image]
2. Add a Remesh Modifier and increase the Voxel Size until the hole gets filled.
   [image]
3. Add a Displace Modifier and adjust the Strength so that the model rests mostly within the original model.
   [image]
4. Add another Remesh Modifier to clean up any self-intersection that may have been caused by the Displace Modifier.
   [image]
5. Apply the modifiers from top to bottom.
   [image]
6. Sculpt back any mesh that is poking through.
   [image]
7. If your slicer doesn't mind and you aren't hollowing, you're done, but if you want one manifold mesh you could either use a Boolean Modifier set to Union, or you could remesh again. To remesh, join the meshes together by selecting both shapes and using Object>Join, remesh with a very low voxel size, and decimate to get back to a lower poly count.

Remeshing and decimating isn't the cleanest, and it can be computationally intensive, but it can also save loads of time spent in manual cleanup or in troubleshooting the Boolean Modifier.

I use a similar process when I want to manually hollow models in Blender.

Comment: Thanks a lot Raymond, this is exactly how I do it :) Remesh high poly + decimate is a life saver. Only thing different is that I use shrink/fatten instead of displace modifier (both leave the nasty border lines when going into negative). However, I was wondering is there some way of not needing to manualy adjust mashes (like sculpting) as I have a really complex mesh and it tends to be very time consuming. Maybe some king of nodes sequence. I need to find the "bottleneck" of the "pockets" and close them somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: You may be able to use an occlusion map to mask out the cavities and then delete or merge them in geometry nodes.
https://youtu.be/RSpkkuOOtBw?t=1427

Comment: I was hoping that the bottlenecks would be narrow enough that you could use a relatively high remesh value and not fill in the crevasses too much.

Answer (score 0):

This does remind me of a file cleanup too I came across a while back for resin printing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UU6tWhV010M&t=844s